# Can't build a qt project using qtservice

Tags: qt, build

I'm trying to use QtService from QtSolution in a Qt project.

I've unzipped it and run:
configure.bat -library
qmake
mingw32-make

the debug and release dll were placed inside C:\Qt\2010.03\qt\bin\
Examples were correctly built .

I added this line at the bottom of my .pro file:
include(../QtSolutions/qtservice/src/qtservice.pri)

and I was able to browse the qtservice's sources from the project source tree.

When I try to build my project I get:

```
Running build steps for project EMCSolutionCrawler...
Configuration unchanged, skipping QMake step.
Starting: C:/Qt/2010.03/mingw/bin/mingw32-make.exe -w 
mingw32-make: Entering directory `C:/Progetti/EMCSolutionCrawler'
c:\qt\2010.03\qt\bin\qmake.exe -spec ..\..\Qt\2010.03\qt\mkspecs\win32-g++ -win32 -o Makefile EMCSolutionCrawler.pro
mingw32-make: Leaving directory `C:/Progetti/EMCSolutionCrawler'
mingw32-make: Entering directory `C:/Progetti/EMCSolutionCrawler'
C:/Qt/2010.03/mingw/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory `C:/Progetti/EMCSolutionCrawler'
g++ -g -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_QTSERVICE_IMPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT ../QtSolutions/qtservice/src/QtService.cpp -o ../QtSolutions/qtservice/src/QtService
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory `C:/Progetti/EMCSolutionCrawler'
mingw32-make: Leaving directory `C:/Progetti/EMCSolutionCrawler'
In file included from ../QtSolutions/qtservice/src/QtService.cpp:47:
../QtSolutions/qtservice/src/qtservice.h:50:35: error: QtCore/QCoreApplication: No such file or directory
In file included from ../QtSolutions/qtservice/src/QtService.cpp:48:
../QtSolutions/qtservice/src/qtservice_p.h:50:30: error: QtCore/QStringList: No such file or directory
../QtSolutions/qtservice/src/QtService.cpp:51:25: error: QtCore/QTimer: No such file or directory
../QtSolutions/qtservice/src/QtService.cpp:52:26: error: QtCore/QVector: No such file or directory
../QtSolutions/qtservice/src/QtService.cpp:53:27: error: QtCore/QProcess: No such file or directory
../QtSolutions/qtservice/src/QtService.cpp:426:25: error: qtservice.moc: No such file or directory
In file included from ../QtSolutions/qtservice/src/QtService.cpp:47:
../QtSolutions/qtservice/src/qtservice.h:73: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE' with no type
../QtSolutions/qtservice/src/qtservice.h:74: error: expected ';' before 'public'
../QtSolutions/qtservice/src/qtservice.h:80: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'QString' with no type
../QtSolutions/qtservice/src/qtservice.h:80: error: expected ',' or '...' before '&' token
../QtSolutions/qtservice/src/qtservice.h:86: error: 'QString' does not name a type
../QtSolutions/qtservice/src/qtservice.h:87: error: 'QString' does not name a type
../QtSolutions/qtservice/src/qtservice.h:88: error: 'StartupType' does not name a type
../QtSolutions/qtservice/src/qtservice.h:89: error: 'QString' does not name a type
../QtSolutions/qtservice/src/qtservice.h:91: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'QString' with no type
../QtSolutions/qtservice/src/qtservice.h:91: error: expected ',' or '...' before '&' token
../QtSolutions/qtservice/src/qtservice.h:110: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE' with no type
../QtSolutions/qtservice/src/qtservice.h:111: error: expected ';' before 'public'
../QtSolutions/qtservice/src/qtservice.h:125: error: 'ServiceFlags' has not been declared
../QtSolutions/qtservice/src/qtservice.h:125: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'Q_DECLARE_FLAGS' with no type
../QtSolutions/qtservice/src/qtservice.h:127: error: expected ';' before 'QtServiceBase'
../QtSolutions/qtservice/src/qtservice.h:130: error: 'QString' does not name a type
...
```

What am I missing?

Environment infomation:
Qt 4.6.3 (mingw - LGPL)
Windows XP SP3
QtService 2.6

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: I don't see a include `-IC:\Qt\2010.03\qt\include` in your call of `g++`. So the compiler can't find the Qt Headers. I tink there is something wrong in your **EMCSolutionCrawler.pro**.

Comment: the problem wasn't in the .pro file:
<pre>
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console \
    qt
QT = core \
    network \
    sql

# QT += network sql
# QT -= gui
TARGET = EMCSolutionCrawler

# CONFIG += console
# CONFIG -= app_bundle
# TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp \
    crawlerservice.cpp
HEADERS += crawlerservice.h

include(../QtSolutions/qtservice/src/qtservice.pri)
</pre>
if I qmake and mingw32-make the project it builds without errors. Errors bubble up only if I use QtCreator to build it.
I need a little time more to investigate and solve this issue but I'll update my post with the solution.

Comment: Okay. But there are now include directories given for your g++ call. So the compiler can't find the declartion of `QtCore/QApplication` etc.